# Errors when adding an action to a JFrame button to edit a picture previously selected

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, image-editor

I am trying to make a ImageEditor in Java, for a school project. Until now I managed to make with JFrame the menu with two submenus: open - where i can search for a picture and see it in the main window; and clear - where i clear the main window. This part works okey. Lately I added also with Jframe 4 buttons, in order to edit the picture and make it grayscale, in sepia tones, negative or red/green/blue.

I am still stuck at the first button where I need to make the picture in grey tones. I found the algorithm but i have no idea how can i get rid of this errors.The code looks like this:

```
package myPackage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class ImageEditor extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JFileChooser img = new JFileChooser();
    static BufferedImage image;

public ImageEditor() {
    initComponents();
}
private ImageEditor(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;
}

private static void write(BufferedImage image, String jpg, JFileChooser img) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

private static void write(BufferedImage image, String jpg, File f) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jSP = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jB_Greyscale = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jB_Sepia = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jB_RGB = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jB_Negative = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMI_Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMI_Clear = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jB_Greyscale.setText("Black & White");
    jB_Greyscale.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jB_GreyscaleActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jB_Sepia.setText("Sepia");

    jB_RGB.setText("Red/Green/Blue");

    jB_Negative.setText("Negative");

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    jMI_Open.setText("Open");
    jMI_Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMI_OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMI_Open);

    jMI_Clear.setText("Clear");
    jMI_Clear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMI_ClearActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMI_Clear);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(jB_Greyscale, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jB_Sepia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jB_RGB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jB_Negative, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 285, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jSP)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jB_Greyscale)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jB_Sepia)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jB_RGB)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jB_Negative)
            .addGap(0, 169, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


//Create a label
JLabel jlab = new JLabel();
private void jMI_OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Creez file chooser
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    //Selectez poza si o afisez
    if(jfc.showOpenDialog(jMenu1) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        //Select the path
        java.io.File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();

        //Set icon
        jlab.setIcon(new ImageIcon(f.toString()));

        //Alignment
        jlab.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        //Add label for jScrollPane
        jSP.getViewport().add(jlab);

        //Save image for futher edit
        img = jfc;
    }   
}                                        

private void jMI_ClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    //Clear image from jlabel jlab
    jlab.setIcon(null);
}                                         



private void jB_GreyscaleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //Get image dimension
    ImageEditor.write(image,"jpg",img);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int p = 0, a, r, g, b, avg, y, x;

    //Convert to grayscale
    for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
            p = image.getRGB(x,y);
            a = (p >> 24)&0xff;
            r = (p >> 16)&0xff;
            g = (p >> 8)&0xff;
            b = p >> 0xff;

            //Calculate the average
            avg = (r+g+b)/3;

            //Replace RGB values with the average
            p = (a << 24) | (avg << 16) | (avg << 8) | avg;

            image.setRGB(x, y, p);
    }       

    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Iulia\\Grayscale.jpg");
    ImageEditor.write(image, "jpg", f);
}                                            

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageEditor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageEditor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageEditor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageEditor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ImageEditor().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jB_Greyscale;
private javax.swing.JButton jB_Negative;
private javax.swing.JButton jB_RGB;
private javax.swing.JButton jB_Sepia;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMI_Clear;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMI_Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jSP;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

And the error i get when i click on the grayscale button:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at myPackage.ImageEditor.write(ImageEditor.java:33)
at myPackage.ImageEditor.jB_GreyscaleActionPerformed(ImageEditor.java:155)
at myPackage.ImageEditor.access$000(ImageEditor.java:21)
at myPackage.ImageEditor$1.actionPerformed(ImageEditor.java:59)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line from your functions

`throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`

Comment: @lulia Dobra Are you using netbeans? If yes, which version?

Comment: I am using NetBeans  v 8.0.2

Comment: Then its fine.. check in your code only.. there should not be the above line in your whole code.

Comment: I also have no idea how to get the image from the imageviewer so i can use it in the grayscale function. Can you help me with that? I think that's why i get all the errors. They appear after i load the picture, when i press the grayscale button